# how can I sign up using rest API in react js application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, fetch

I have got this API but I can't able to sign up with this. let me help what I need to sign up creating from this API.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://www.jptmemes.com/api/signup' 

 - --data-urlencode 'username=' 
   --data-urlencode 'email=' 
   --data-urlencode 'password=' 
   --data-urlencode 'confirm_password=' 
   --data-urlencode 'phone=' 
   --data-urlencode 'first_name=' 
   --data-urlencode 'last_name=' 
   --data-urlencode 'gcm_token='
   --data-urlencode 'avatar='
```

Comment: Whats the issue here?

Comment: When you hit the endpoint, are you filling out the required fields for username, email, password etc?

Comment: I am unsure about gcm_token and avatar